# Django multiple delete record

Tags: django

How do i delete multiple record in django?

```
    idproduct = request.POST.get('relatedid')
    products = GroupAndProduct.objects.filter(id=idproduct)
    record=GroupAndProduct.objects.get(id=products)
    record.delete()
```

[image]

Comment: first get object list using `filter` then use `delete`. ex: `GroupAndProduct.objects.filter(id=idproduct).delete()`

Comment: please see my updated question

Comment: if 2nd line have multiple objects then just use `products.delete()` instead of line 4 and line 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `record = GroupAndProduct.objects.get(id=products)` is responsible for this error. Because `get` method requires exact lookup (for instance pk=1) but you send a queryset to another queryset's filter to get an object.
First of all make sure that you know the type of `idproduct = request.POST.get('relatedid')`. If the `idproduct` is a list of ids, then you should do something like:

```
GroupAndProduct.objects.filter(id__in=idproduct).delete()
```

to delete multiple `GroupAndProduct` instances. But if `idproduct` is a  number (or string type of a number) you should use:

```
GroupAndProduct.objects.filter(id=idproduct).delete()
```

So I think changing your codes to something like:

```
idproduct = request.POST.get('relatedid')
GroupAndProduct.objects.filter(id__in=idproduct).delete() # or .filter(id=idproduct).delete()
```

will solve your problem. Both of the solutions will delete all records that satisfies the queryset filter.